# Workaround for static member inheritance in C#

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

For my purposes I have a base class for a number of database-based objects (not exactly but let's keep it this way for clarity).
All of the derived classes need a `TableName` member which contains the name of the database table.

What I need is a way to fulfill all of the following points:

1. The following function should work with all of the derived classes:

   ```
   List<T> ReadAll<T>() where T: BaseClass, new()
   {
       List resultList = new List();
       var results = doQuery("SELECT * FROM " + T.TableName);
       foreach (var r in results)
       {
           resultList.Add(new T(r));
       }
       return resultList;
   }
   ```

   (reads all records from the table - needs the table name)
2. Inheritance from the base class needs to compel me to add/override the TableName member whenever I create a new derived class, otherwise the code should not compile (it's one of its purposes anyway);
3. The `TableName` member should be static (or something to that purpose), since I shouldn't need a "fake" instance of the derived type just to access a constant member for the sake of point 1.

Now, assuming my purposes are sensible and not based on wrong assumptions, how can I attain all of these purposes considering that (for good reasons) C# doesn't allow inheritance of static members?
If instead you think I'm wrong in assuming that all of the points should be attainable together, how do you think I should change my design?

Comment: When do you need table names without an instance related to that table?

Comment: Use attribute, this is how most of issues like this are resolved?

Comment: @xxbbcc: I need it if I have to `"select * from " + T.TableName` and only afterwards `foreach r in result { list.Add(new T(r)); }`

Comment: @dr4cul4: I might end up using it, I just hoped to find something that addressed all of my points (mainly enforcing by compiler).

Comment: You can euforię this at runtime start..  or add command line switch to do it at start of application (usefull for build machines).

Comment: @SnailMan Your table name should probably be assigned to the business object / repository object that performs the database operation, not the entity. The entity could have a copy of it after creation or have a way to get to the repository and access it. This is mostly preference-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't override static members, so having a static field for the sake of being different per class usually won't work. If you need such data per class, you're talking about *metadata*, which can be created using Attributes

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class TableNameAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly string _name;
    public string Name {get { return _name; } }

    public TableNameAttribute(string name) { _name = name; }
}
```

And then on each class

```
[TableName("Derived")]
public class DerviedClass { /*...*/ }
```

This cannot be cheked at compile time, however, so you'll need to make sure to add proper handling when `[TableName]` is not present on a given class. If you need to be compelled to always make sure the attribute is present, write some good unit tests, perhaps noe which scans your assembly and checks for all types being tagged appropriately, or follow the "all code must be run once before comitting" rule. Note that by enforcing this at *runtime* with good practices and testing, you'll also more readily dodge the inevitable headache of a mispelled table name.

Using attributes, though, you won't *need* to constrain your generic to a singular type, unless you write a static property to access the table name attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a static member to force each class to require a "TableName" member - just make it an abstract property:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public abstract string TableName {get;}
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
   public override string TableName {get {return "Derived";} }
}
```

Making it `abstract` forces inherited classes to implement the property - whether they do it using a static property, a constant, a read only property, or something else is up to them.

Comment: Thanks but, as of point 3, I need something that doesn't force me to instantiate a "fake" BaseClass object just for the sake of getting the value.

Comment: Post an example of how you want to call it statically - static calls are bound at compile-time so there's no way to override or dynamically dispatch them.

Comment: I know I can't override static fields, I hoped to find some workaround that still enabled me to have it the way I need it. An example is: `List<T> ReadAll<T>() where T: BaseClass { List<T> resultList = new List<T>(); var results = FunctionThatMakesAQuery("select * from " + T.TableName); foreach var r in results { resultList.Add(new T(r)); } return resultList; } `

Comment: (added example in question)

Comment: You can't call static methods on `T`.  Static calls are bound at compile time, and you don't know the type of `T` at compile time.  There are other ways (attributes, reflection, etc.) but they will mostly be run-time bound.

Comment: You _could_ create a helper method that would create a T or use reflection to the the property, but there's not a way to dynamically bind static calls.

Comment: Yes, sorry, in order to simplify I posted incorrect code. I'm currently using reflection but in fact it doesn't seem to be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems here:

1. You need static member inheritance, which C# doesn't support.
2. You are trying to hard-code table names into a set of classes, so you are ending up with a diffusion of responsibility. If the table names need to change, you potentially have to go to multiple places in the code to fix the problem.

The solution to both is to have a single location that eg contains a dictionary that maps class names to table names. Then each derived class can call the following protected method from `BaseClass` in their constructors to get their own table names:

```
protected string TableName()
{
    return ClassTableMappings.GetTableName(this.GetType().Name);
}
```